# Multi-class classification with discrete output: Which loss function and activation to choose?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function, multiclass-classification

I'm working with a multi-class classification problem, using Keras Sequential models. In my dataset, the output class has one of the following values:
`(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`.

Yes, I have already tried one-hot-encoding the output and using `categorical_crossentropy` as a loss function and `softmax` in the output layer.

However, I don't think that softmax and categorical cross entropy is the right choice in my case. In my dataset, the output classes have a certain "discreteness" (or scale). Class `1` is the "worst" and class `5` is the "best".

Let's say if on a specific input the model predicts `2` and the true class is `1`, it's a much better prediction as when the model predicts class `5` and true class is `1`.

I would like, that the loss function would take these "minor errors" into consideration and not treat all errors the same way.

**To sum up, I'm wondering what my options are in terms of loss function and activation of the output layer for my given problem.**

Comment: Update for everyone dealing with a similar problem:

1. Try using `mean_squared_error` as your loss function, with an output layer: `Dense(1, activation='linear')`.
2. Another suggestion I received form @naive was to look into [ordinal regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_regression).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements, I would highly suggest for you to **create your Loss function**.
This way you can handle the results the way you wanted it to be. Basically in creating your Loss Function, you only need the **y_pred** and the **y_true**, then **return this as a Tensor**.

It is also worth noting that when Creating any **customized loss**, **optimizer**, and **layers**. It is **only allowed to use Tensor Flow backend operations**, as using libraries like **Numpy** will result in **compilation** **errors**.

Here is the [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training#define_a_loss_function) to the Documentation in Tensor Flow in doing **Custom Training** in your model.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out - the reason why I didn't go into custom loss functions is that I found out that `mean_squared_error` is actually quite a good fit for my problem.